# How to write all keys and values within Dictionary<string, object> to a text file?

Tags: c#, json, serialization, streamwriter

I have a `Dictionary<string, object> advertiserResponse` that looks like this...

```
"AdvertiserLookup": {
          "Agency": {
            "AgencyAlpha": "ABC",
            "Media": [
              {
                "Code": "123",
                "Name": "XYZ",
                "Advertisers": {
                  "Advertiser": [
                    {
                      "Code": "JKL",
                      "Name": "EFG",
                      "BusinessKey": "HIJ"
                    },
                    {
                      "Code": "KLM",
                      "Name": "NOP",
                      "BusinessKey": "QRS"
                    },
                    {
```

This is the line I'm using to try to write to a text file:

```
File.WriteAllLines("test.txt", advertiserResponse.Select(x => "[" + x.Key + " " + x.Value + "]").ToArray());
```

I'm expecting the Json (**not necessary** in pretty print) with all keys and text below `AdvertiserLookup`.
What I get in `test.txt`:

``` [AdvertiserLookup System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary``2[System.String,System.Object]] ```

How do I write the entire thing to text?

Comment: I guess you noticed that this is hierarchical, no?

Comment: The Dictionary can't looks like this, it is just JSON representation of the data contained in Dictionary. You can save the data as JSON before converting it to Dictionary.

Comment: I propose to parse this as JSON and use the proper internal representation for it instead Dictionary. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6620165/how-to-parse-json-in-c You can then easily dump out the data into a string like in the linked example `JsonConvert.SerializeObject(product);`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Give [Json.NET](https://json.codeplex.com/) a try. You should be able to serialize your dictionary.

```
var jsonString = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(advertiserResponse, Formatting.Indented)
```